# Exception Access Violation in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having intermittent trouble with an OPENQUERY statement that pulls data through ODBC from a Progress database into SQL 2005. Most of the time it works, but every couple weeks, one of the many calls using this method bombs with a SQL Stack dump, shown below. We've run exhaustive hardware checks and also DB integrity checks, and have come up empty.

=====================================================================

## BugCheck Dump

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server
version 9.00.4035.00
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.

Computer type is AT/AT COMPATIBLE.
Bios Version is HP     - 2
Current time is 22:25:51 07/07/09.
8 Intel x86 level 6, 2400 Mhz processor (s).
Windows NT 5.2 Build 3790 CSD Service Pack 1.

Memory
MemoryLoad = 86%
Total Physical = 32764 MB
Available Physical = 4310 MB
Total Page File = 34447 MB
Available Page File = 6117 MB
Total Virtual = 2047 MB
Available Virtual = 155 MB
***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0032.txt
SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 122 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is
 terminating this process.

---

- - BEGIN STACK DUMP:
- 07/07/09 22:25:51 spid 122
- - 
- Exception Address = 6D4A01D2 Module(pgoe1023+000801D2)
- Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
- Access Violation occurred reading address 00000010
- Input Buffer 510 bytes -
- --Import all data from QAD into local tables  truncate table
- qad.pi_mstr  insert into qad.pi_mstr select 'QADDB', * from openquery(QA
- DPWPSPRES,'select * from pub.pi_mstr WITH (NOLOCK)')  insert into qad.pi
- _mstr select 'Paragon', * from openquery(QADPWPSPPARA,'select * from pub
- .pi_mstr WITH (NOLOCK)')    --Copy desired subset of data over into the
- end result table  truncate table PriceListMasterCustomer  insert into Pr
- iceListMasterCustomer (PriceListID, CustomerPriceList, PriceListDescript
- ion, CustomerAnalysisCode, ItemAnalysisCode, StartDate, ExpireDate, ModD
- ate, CombType, AmountType,                         BreakCategory, PI_UM,
- Curr, QtyType, CostSet, ConfgDisc, CustomerType, PartType, UserID, Disc
- Sequence, ListPrice, MinNet, MaxQty, Manual)  SELECT     pi_list_id, pi_
- list, pi_desc, pi_cs_code, pi_part_code, pi_start, pi_expire, pi_mod_dat
- e, pi_comb_type, pi_amt_type, pi_break_cat, pi_um, pi_curr, pi_qty_type,
- pi_cost_set, pi_confg_disc, pi_cs_type, pi_part
- _type, pi_userid, pi_disc_seq, pi_list_price, pi_min_net, pi_max_qty, pi
- _manual  FROM         qad.pi_mstr  where dbname = 'QADDB'
- - 
- MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE
- sqlservr                       01000000  02C1FFFF  01c20000
- ntdll                          7C800000  7C8C1FFF  000c2000
- kernel32                       77E40000  77F42FFF  00103000
- MSVCR80                        78130000  781CAFFF  0009b000
- msvcrt                         77BA0000  77BF9FFF  0005a000
- MSVCP80                        7C420000  7C4A6FFF  00087000
- ADVAPI32                       77F50000  77FEBFFF  0009c000
- RPCRT4                         77C50000  77CEEFFF  0009f000
- sqlos                          344D0000  344D4FFF  00005000
- Secur32                        76F50000  76F62FFF  00013000
- USERENV                        76920000  769E3FFF  000c4000
- USER32                         77380000  77411FFF  00092000
- GDI32                          77C00000  77C48FFF  00049000
- WINMM                          76AA0000  76ACCFFF  0002d000
- opends60                       333E0000  333E6FFF  00007000
- NETAPI32                       71C40000  71C97FFF  00058000
- IMM32                          76290000  762ACFFF  0001d000
- psapi                          76B70000  76B7AFFF  0000b000
- instapi                        48060000  48069FFF  0000a000
- sqlevn70                       4F610000  4F7B8FFF  001a9000
- rsaenh                         68000000  6802EFFF  0002f000
- AUTHZ                          76C40000  76C53FFF  00014000
- MSCOREE                        79000000  79045FFF  00046000
- ole32                          62A40000  62B73FFF  00134000
- msv1_0                         76C90000  76CB6FFF  00027000
- iphlpapi                       76CF0000  76D09FFF  0001a000
- WS2_32                         71C00000  71C16FFF  00017000
- WS2HELP                        71BF0000  71BF7FFF  00008000
- kerberos                       62BF0000  62C47FFF  00058000
- cryptdll                       766E0000  766EBFFF  0000c000
- MSASN1                         76190000  761A1FFF  00012000
- schannel                       76750000  76776FFF  00027000
- CRYPT32                        761B0000  76242FFF  00093000
- COMRES                         62CB0000  62D75FFF  000c6000
- XOLEHLP                        62D80000  62D85FFF  00006000
- MSDTCPRX                       62D90000  62E07FFF  00078000
- OLEAUT32                       77D00000  77D8BFFF  0008c000
- msvcp60                        780C0000  78120FFF  00061000
- MTXCLU                         62E10000  62E28FFF  00019000
- VERSION                        77B90000  77B97FFF  00008000
- WSOCK32                        71BB0000  71BB8FFF  00009000
- CLUSAPI                        62E30000  62E41FFF  00012000
- RESUTILS                       62E50000  62E62FFF  00013000
- mswsock                        71B20000  71B60FFF  00041000
- DNSAPI                         76ED0000  76EF8FFF  00029000
- winrnr                         62EC0000  62EC6FFF  00007000
- WLDAP32                        76F10000  76F3DFFF  0002e000
- rasadhlp                       62EF0000  62EF7FFF  00008000
- security                       632C0000  632C3FFF  00004000
- msfte                          63C20000  63E78FFF  00259000
- dbghelp                        63E90000  63FA4FFF  00115000
- WINTRUST                       76BB0000  76BDAFFF  0002b000
- imagehlp                       76C10000  76C38FFF  00029000
- dssenh                         68100000  68123FFF  00024000
- hnetcfg                        641F0000  64248FFF  00059000
- wshtcpip                       71AE0000  71AE7FFF  00008000
- NTMARTA                        77E00000  77E21FFF  00022000
- SAMLIB                         64310000  6431EFFF  0000f000
- ntdsapi                        766F0000  76704FFF  00015000
- xpsp2res                       643A0000  64664FFF  002c5000
- CLBCatQ                        64670000  646F2FFF  00083000
- sqlncli                        64700000  64926FFF  00227000
- COMCTL32                       64930000  649C6FFF  00097000
- comdlg32                       00750000  00799FFF  0004a000
- SHELL32                        7C8D0000  7D0D3FFF  00804000
- SHLWAPI                        77DA0000  77DF1FFF  00052000
- comctl32                       649D0000  64AD2FFF  00103000
- SQLNCLIR                       64C00000  64C32FFF  00033000
- msftepxy                       64DD0000  64DE4FFF  00015000
- xpsqlbot                       667D0000  667D5FFF  00006000
- xpstar90                       667F0000  6683AFFF  0004b000
- SQLSCM90                       66850000  66858FFF  00009000
- ODBC32                         66870000  668ACFFF  0003d000
- BatchParser90                  668B0000  668CEFFF  0001f000
- ATL80                          7C630000  7C64AFFF  0001b000
- odbcint                        66BA0000  66BB6FFF  00017000
- xpstar90                       66BC0000  66BE5FFF  00026000
- xplog70                        66BF0000  66BFBFFF  0000c000
- xplog70                        66C10000  66C12FFF  00003000
- msxmlsql                       78800000  788D4FFF  000d5000
- msxml2                         67C50000  67CFEFFF  000af000
- msxml3                         69730000  6984AFFF  0011b000
- oledb32                        6A250000  6A2C8FFF  00079000
- MSDART                         698D0000  698E9FFF  0001a000
- OLEDB32R                       6B7F0000  6B800FFF  00011000
- msdasql                        6D1F0000  6D23CFFF  0004d000
- MSDATL3                        6D240000  6D254FFF  00015000
- MSDASQLR                       68150000  68153FFF  00004000
- comsvcs                        6D260000  6D398FFF  00139000
- pgoe1023                       6D420000  6D50EFFF  000ef000
- pgicu23                        6D510000  6E108FFF  00bf9000
- odbccp32                       6E120000  6E139FFF  0001a000
- pgoe1023R                      63BB0000  63BC5FFF  00016000
- dbghelp                        70380000  70494FFF  00115000
- - Edi: 6E8382E4:  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000031  00000CE3  00000001
- Esi: 6E7E2364:  6D4D7DCC  6E18AFD0  6E88ED38  00000000  00000000  00000000
- Eax: 00000042:
- Ebx: 00000000:
- Ecx: 00000000:
- Edx: 00000023:
- Eip: 6D4A01D2:  8B10518B  4E8B9A04  C1835004  09ACE808  C3830000  745E3B01
- Ebp: 00000000:
- SegCs: 0000001B:
- EFlags: 00010206:  006E0069  0000005C  0055004E  0042004D  00520045  004F005F
- Esp: 6872F0AC:  6E7E2364  6E80265C  6E18AFD0  00000000  6872F0FC  00000000
- SegSs: 00000023:

  ---
- ---
- Short Stack Dump
  6D4A01D2 Module(pgoe1023+000801D2)

### PSS @0x39449328

### CSession @0x39448278

m_spid = 122                         m_cRef = 12                          m_rgcRefType[0] = 1
m_rgcRefType[1] = 1                  m_rgcRefType[2] = 9                  m_rgcRefType[3] = 1
m_rgcRefType[4] = 0                  m_rgcRefType[5] = 0                  m_pmo = 0x39448040
m_pstackBhfPool = 0x00000000         m_dwLoginFlags = 0x83e0              m_fBackground = 0
m_fClientRequestConnReset = 0        m_fUserProc = -1                     m_fConnReset = 0
m_fIsConnReset = 0                   m_fInLogin = 0                       m_fAuditLoginSent = 1
m_fAuditLoginFailedSent = 0          m_fReplRelease = 0                   m_fKill = 0
m_ulLoginStamp = 7684188             m_eclClient = 5                      m_protType = 6
m_hHttpToken = FFFFFFFF

### m_pV7LoginRec

00000000:   48010000 03000a73 401f0000 00000006 740b0000 †H......s@.......t...

00000014:   00000000 e0830000 00000000 00000000 5e000d00 †................^...

00000028:   00000000 00000000 78001c00 b0000d00 ca000000 †........x...........

0000003C:   ca001c00 02010000 02010500 001cc493 53260c01 †................S&..

00000050:   3c004801 00004801 00000000 0000†††††††††††††††<.H...H.......

### CPhysicalConnection @0x39448188

m_pPhyConn->m_pmo = 0x39448040       m_pPhyConn->m_pNetConn = 0x394487B0  m_pPhyConn->m_pConnList = 0x39448260
m_pPhyConn->m_pSess = 0x39448278     m_pPhyConn->m_fTracked = -1          m_pPhyConn->m_cbPacketsize = 8000
m_pPhyConn->m_fMars = 0              m_pPhyConn->m_fKill = 0

### CBatch @0x39448AB8

m_pSess = 0x39448278                 m_pConn = 0x39448A18                 m_cRef = 3
m_rgcRefType[0] = 1                  m_rgcRefType[1] = 1                  m_rgcRefType[2] = 1
m_rgcRefType[3] = 0                  m_rgcRefType[4] = 0                  m_pTask = 0x008C86B8

### EXCEPT (null) @0x6872D680

exc_number = 0                       exc_severity = 0                     exc_func = 0x024231C0

### Task @0x008C86B8

CPU Ticks used (ms) = 309469         Task State = 2
WAITINFO_INTERNAL: WaitResource = 0x00000000                              WAITINFO_INTERNAL: WaitType = 0x0
WAITINFO_INTERNAL: WaitSpinlock = 0x00000000
WAITINFO_EXTERNAL: WaitResource = 0x00000000                              WAITINFO_EXTERNAL: WaitType = 0x40006D 
WAITINFO_EXTERNAL: WaitSpinlock = 0x00000000                              SchedulerId = 0x1
ThreadId = 0x1b08                    m_state = 0                          m_eAbortSev = 0

### EC @0x39449330

spid = 122                           ecid = 0                             ec_stat = 0x0
ec_stat2 = 0x0                       ec_atomic = 0x0                      __fSubProc = 1
ec_dbccContext = 0x00000000          __pSETLS = 0x39448A58                __pSEParams = 0x39448CF8
__pDbLocks = 0x39449818

### SEInternalTLS @0x39448A58

```
m_flags = 0                             m_TLSstatus = 3                         m_owningTask = 0x008C86B8             
m_activeHeapDatasetList = 0x39448A58                                        m_activeIndexDatasetList = 0x39448A60
```

### SEParams @0x39448CF8

```
m_lockTimeout = -1                      m_isoLevel = 4096                       m_logDontReplicate = 0                
m_neverReplicate = 0                    m_XactWorkspace = 0x416CA2D0            m_pSessionLocks = 0x39449A28          
m_pDbLocks = 0x39449818                 m_execStats = 0x52133778                m_pAllocFileLimit = 0x00000000
```

Comment: In my case (Sqlserver 2017) exception access violation occurred when i delete record from specific table, issue resolved when i install cumulative Update 8 for SQL Server 2017 from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338363/cumulative-update-8-for-sql-server-2017), you can also install other updates as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your input is hitting some kind of lock in the source database and it's crashing the import process? I know it's a longshot, and I would expect ODBC to fail more gracefully if it encounters something like that, but the fact that it's intermittant would suggest that it's something like this. What other processes run in the neighborhood of the schedule for this one? Are there any other potential conflicts?

I'm not knowledgable about Progress, but there seem to be some complaints online that the ODBC driver isn't graceful at all when there's a problem, so it could be something simple that's causing this error. Is there a way to enable any sort of logging so that you don't have rely on what SQL reports the error as, but can use some kind of output from the ODBC driver itself?

Comment: I've never found OPENQUERY, OPENROWSET etc. to be reliable against a different database. Never. Do you have the option of using an ETL tool to perform this in batch because that is reliable. Unless you have a direct phone to the Progress ODBC developer this will not be solved. The problem isn't really with SQL it's with the ODBC driver (and SQL's inability to handle some bug or unexpected behaviour in it). Basically if this is occurring in batch (i.e. not on demand but once or twice a day)? then I suggest you externalise it in an ETL or batch process to stop your database crashing.