# How can I debug an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

An application that uses a database broke suddenly. I started to investigate and noticed that a simple count query

```
SELECT count(uberdataid) FROM [Alexander].[dbo].[UberData]
```

creates an error in SQL Server:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discard

A few thoughts:

- When I check out the error's stack trace it says that there is an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. The name of that exception makes me think that there might be a permissions issue in the query. But I  get this exact same error on many different user accounts (which all were able to query the DB without issue before).
- This discussion on SO (  [Exception Access Violation in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098392/exception-access-violation-in-sql)) makes me think that the query might be hitting a lingering record lock, but I've rebooted the server so that seems unlikely.

There are also some other unresolved discussions on other message boards online.

Any ideas?

Stackoverflow won't let me post the whole trace (too long) but I am happy to post relevant parts if people need to see them. I don't know what parts from the trace are most important to post.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I know nothing of SQL Server.  An access violation indicates the sql server is hitting a segmentation fault.  That would be a Bad Thing.  It's possible your table is corrupted somehow.  You might try an old backup from before the issue to see if that one doesn't experience it.  Other than that, if this is simple to reproduce, you might have found a bug.

Comment: What is the build of SQL Server (SELECT @@VERSION)? Most access violations are bugs, and most have been fixed, but they are difficult to test and prove except in the environment where the AV is happening.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: In my case (Sqlserver 2017) exception access violation occurred when i delete record from specific table, issue resolved when i install cumulative Update 8 for SQL Server 2017 from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338363/cumulative-update-8-for-sql-server-2017), you can also install other updates as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a SQL Server bug. `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` means that code inside of SQL Server tried to access "invalid" memory (for example, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer). It has nothing to do with SQL Server security settings.

Even though this is likely to be a bug, I recommend that you run

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS, DATA_PURITY, NO_INFOMSGS
```

on the database in question. There might be corruption that is triggering a SQL Server bug.

Comment: Running that check gives this error: Msg 1823, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 A database snapshot cannot be created because it failed to start.Msg 7928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The database snapshot for online checks could not be created. Either the reason is given in a previous error or one of the underlying volumes does not support sparse files or alternate streams. Attempting to get exclusive access to run checks offline.

Comment: Msg 5030, Level 16, State 12, Line 1
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
Msg 7926, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check statement aborted. The database could not be checked as a database snapshot could not be created and the database or table could not be locked. See Books Online for details of when this behavior is expected and what workarounds exist. Also see previous errors for more details.

Comment: Can you put the database in single-user mode first (ALTER DATABASE DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE)? That will allow the lock to be taken.

Comment: so run ALTER DATABASE DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE and then run DBCC CHECKDB WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS, DATA_PURITY, NO_INFOMSGS

Comment: Yes. If this doesn't work there is a ton of information on the web on how to run CHECKDB. I think you should really try it.

Comment: that fixed the issue. thanks! would not have known how to do that.