# Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on Proc where I want to check data in TableA which is in other DB and if all (5 to 6 IF conditions)  satisfies then insert data into TableB which is in another DB.  If all the IF condition satisfies for particular row then that row data should to be inserted into TableB . Both the databases are in same server.however while inserting data in Table A it fails with the severe error.

i am using cursor inside the Proc.

I have checked the error dump but nothing can be identified.

- BEGIN STACK DUMP:
- 09/07/17 12:17:44 spid 52
  *
  *
- Exception Address = 000007FEEBBA7BA6 Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)
- Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
- Access Violation occurred reading address 0000000000000000
- Input Buffer 100 bytes -

Comment: Please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512192/1050927.  And also try to upgrade your sql server to latest patch.

Comment: Did it generate a mini dump file? You can use windbg and public symbols to see the stack trace at the time of the crash and then search for that.

Comment: Or if you don't fancy doing that yourself you can try this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/