# Bulk Insert csv trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2000). On that server I execute `BULK INSERT` for about 200 files in range from 1 kB to 35 MB in this way:

```
BULK INSERT [MYDB].[dbo].[my_table]
FROM 'C:\Docs\csv\001.csv'
WITH 
    (FIRSTROW = 1,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
     TABLOCK,
     KEEPNULLS);
```

All my `.csv` files are syntactically correct. In that way everything works for 2 days.

After that I suddenly get this error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

And even files that have been inserted previously now are discarded. When I try to insert manually file with one row, it also raises error.

P.S. There is enough disk space on my hard drive.

Comment: Possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175244/sql-server-error-on-update-command-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-com

Comment: Are you using any sql transaction?

Comment: If the recommendation from @AaronDietz for checking the table for corruptions doesn't turn anything up, also run CHECKDB.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511810/how-can-i-debug-an-exception-access-violation-on-sql-server-2008/11512192#11512192

Comment: @SerkanArslan no any sql transactions are used

Comment: @AlGiorgio check my answer update

Comment: I would test with a new table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Possible cause

1. According to this Microsoft artilce :[FIX: An error message may occur when you run a "BULK INSERT" query on a database that uses the "BULK_LOGGED" or "SIMPLE" recovery model in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2297709/fix-an-error-message-may-occur-when-you-run-a-bulk-insert-query-on-a-d):

> This issue occurs because of an error in SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, or SQL Server 2014.

And the proposed solution was to install [Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2931693)

2. Also this may be caused due to a **corrupted index**.

Possible solution: **Try rebuilding indexes**

---

## Possible Workarounds

*If the error is related to BULK INSERT method*

### (1) Using Microsoft Text Driver

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DefaultDir=C:\Docs\csv\;',
'SELECT * FROM 001.csv')
```

### (2) Using OLEDB provider

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
OPENROWSET
        (
            'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\Docs\csv\;IMEX=1;','SELECT * 
FROM 001.csv'
        ) t
```

### References

- [How to import csv file with OPENROWSET?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/import-csv/)
- [T-SQL – Read CSV files using OpenRowSet](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset)

Comment: How will this help with a corrupted index, table, database? Why assume that BULK INSERT is broken but OLEDB is not?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with that, But i provided this answer as a workaround, and i am waiting for a feedback. If it doesn't help than i will try to give more suggestions.

Comment: Why you are assuming that this is due to a corrupted index?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this error is mentioned by microsoft at it is a software bug, check the link i added to my asnwer

Comment: because I googled the error, checked the docs and that's a very common reason. I did check the link, and this is one possibility, although it mentions multiple inserts in a single transactino. That's more helpful. Besides, if you check the link it mentions SSIS. SSIS itself uses JET and OLEDB to load CSV data. It's the *BULK INSERT* part that fails.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos after googling i found that `A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded` is a generic error message that can be thrown in many cases. And it may due to a software bug or a crashed index or corrupted database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my answer to mention that this may be a possible workarounds *(if we are talking about software bug)*.

Comment: System was stable in about week and it seems that updating to stable version is the problem solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Look in the SQL Log for more details.

> 12.0.2000.

You are running an unsupported service pack level for SQL 2014.  You should apply the latest service pack before doing much more troubleshooting of a problem like this:

- [How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958069/how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2014)

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't actually answer the question. BULK INSERT didn't need a service pack to work in SQL Server 2014 RTM anyway. This specific error is usually returned due to corruption. Installing a service pack is *not* going to help in this case, unless there is a know fix for this issue

Comment: "A severe error occurred on the current command" is a generic client error, and often indicates a crash or bug.  Both of which can only be triaged on a supported version.

Answer (score 0):

You may have newline symbols '\r\n'.  So to define a new line in .txt file \r\n symbols are used. You will not see them if you open it in text editor.  You have to turn on invisible characters mode.  You can use notepad++ to see them.

Then you save information in .csv file.  But .csv does not have a special meaning for \r\n symbols.  As a result, they are displayed as is.

You have to remove \r\n symbols in your code directly.  Or, create an app (using C#, VB.NET, etc) to loop through the files and do all the work for you.  I had to do exactly that a few years ago, at a previous job.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline